# Starting a JS Function on Python Flask Form on Submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, forms, flask

I've been wracking my brain on this for a decent portion of today. Mostly because I lack the knowledge in JS to troubleshoot my issue. I've googled countless questions, tried several ideas found on different sites and they've helped me a little bit, but I hit a brick wall.

Background: I've hacked together a status bar to show the user the status of the task happening in the background in my Flask app. It partially works. But not exactly how I want it to. The script is used to input an Excel document and spit out PDFs. I've taken out a good portion of that code, because there is a ton of logic to redact fields from the file before it goes to PDF.

I will start off with my repo: https://github.com/haincha/excel2pdf/

That is all of my code for the project. But I will detail the relevant code below:

In my app.py

```
@celery.task(bind=True)
def long_task(self):
    """Background task that runs a long function with progress reports."""
    array = os.listdir(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'])
    self.update_state(state='PROGRESS',meta={'current': 0, 'total': 1, 'status': 'working...'})
    for i in array:
        if '.xlsx' in i:
            filename = i
    wb = pyexcel.get_sheet(file_name=str(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename)))
    for i in range(0,10):
        number = i * i
        self.update_state(state='PROGRESS',meta={'current': i, 'total': 10, 'status': number})
        time.sleep(1)
    return {'current': 100, 'total': 100, 'status': 'Task completed!','result': 200}

@app.route('/longtask', methods=['POST'])
def longtask():
    task = long_task.apply_async()
    return jsonify({}), 202, {'Location': url_for('taskstatus', task_id=task.id)}

@app.route('/status/<task_id>')
def taskstatus(task_id):
    task = long_task.AsyncResult(task_id)
    if task.state == 'PENDING':
        response = {
            'state': task.state,
            'current': 0,
            'total': 1,
            'status': 'Pending...'
        }
    elif task.state != 'FAILURE':
        response = {
            'state': task.state,
            'current': task.info.get('current', 0),
            'total': task.info.get('total', 1),
            'status': task.info.get('status', '')
        }
        if 'result' in task.info:
            response['result'] = task.info['result']
    else:
        # something went wrong in the background job
        response = {
            'state': task.state,
            'current': 1,
            'total': 1,
            'status': str(task.info),  # this is the exception raised
        }
    return jsonify(response)
```

In my upload.html

```
<form action="{{ url_for('upload') }}" method=POST enctype=multipart/form-data>
<p><input type=file name=excel><input type="submit" value="Upload"></br></br>Account Numbers:</br><textarea name="accounts" style="width:250px;height:150px; float: none;"></textarea></br></br>Starting Tab:</br><input type="text" name="starttab" style="width:40px;"></p>
</form>
<div class="progress">
<div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" id="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 0%"></div>
  </div>
  </div>

   <button id="start-bg-job">Start Long Calculation</button>

<script src="static/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function start_long_task() {
        // add task status elements
        $('#progress');
        // send ajax POST request to start background job
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/longtask',
            success: function(data, status, request) {
                status_url = request.getResponseHeader('Location');
                update_progress(status_url);
            },
            error: function() {
                alert("This alert doesn't help!");
            }
        });
    }
    function update_progress(status_url) {
        // send GET request to status URL
        $.getJSON(status_url, function(data) {
            // update UI
            percent = parseInt(data['current'] * 100 / data['total']);
            $("#progress-bar")
            .css("width", percent + "%")
            .attr("aria-valuenow", percent)
            .text(percent + "%");
            // rerun in 2 seconds
            setTimeout(function() {
                update_progress(status_url);
            }, 2000);
        });
    }
    $(function () {
        $('#start-bg-job').click(start_long_task);
    });
</script>
```

Currently the form submit only uploads the file, and the button outside of the form will kickstart the background process and the progress bar works.

So, some of the things that I have tried are:

Adding id="start-bg-job" to my submit button on my form script. This will upload the file and start the background process. There will be no progress bar update.

Several forms of adding document.getElementById('start-bg-job').submit(); above and below $('#start-bg-job').click(start_long_task);.

Adding on submit tags to the form tag to run_long_task().

Trying to get the button outside of the form to submit the form from the JS portion of the code.

And several other things that are escaping me.

If anyone has any ideas on how to allow only one button to both submit the form and start the JS for the progress bar, I would really appreciate the help.

Comment: You can add a JavaScript event handler for the submit button. If the handler returns `true`, the form will still submit. Use this handler to start the updating of the progress bar, without preventing the form submission from uploading the file.

Comment: Thank you! You pointed me in the direction I needed to be. That portion of the code works now. I can now submit the form, read the file, and show progress the whole way.